# Using foreach to add AD computers to groups

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory-group

This may be the wrong approach, but I have used the last couple of days experimenting with the `foreach` in PowerShell (I use Ver. 5 of PowerShell).

What I am looking for is a way to add a list of computers that I already have into a list of AD groups that I already have. So I used `Get-Content` for importing the 2 .txt files, and I also learned that AD groups in PowerShell uses `-Identity` instead of name I don't know the reason for that decision. But nevertheless I came up with this:

```
$Apps = Get-Content C:\Scripts\Apps.txt
$Computers = Get-Content C:\Scripts\Computers.txt
foreach ($App in $Apps) {
  Add-ADGroupMember $Apps -Identity $Computers
}
```

My problem is that it works of I only have 1 AD group in the `Apps.txt` file. If I add more groups PowerShell goes all red on me, and then my computer starts crying.

In `Computers.txt` I have listed the computer accounts with a `$` at the end, and they are on seperate lines, like this:

```
PC1$
PC2$
```

In `Apps.txt` the AD groups are on seperated lines without any commas or semmicolons or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$Apps` to `$App` in the line `Add-ADGroupMember $Apps -Identity $Computers`
 and also the `-Identity` parameter is the AD Group name. You also will need to use the `-Members` parameter for the users. E.g.

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $App -Members $Computers
```

Comment: He needs to swap the `Identity` and `Members` (implied) parameters as well

Comment: So I chose to split up the text files I am using into a seperate folder and tried all over from a clean console. Now it seems to work. Thanks for the help. Both of you.